# Mouseenter/Mouseleave on area

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, mouseevent

Hey there i got a little question. I am doing a mouseenter and mouseleave on an area:

50% already solved:

```
$("area.anyClass").on('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).addClass('hovered'); // works!
});

$("area.hovered").on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hovered'); // does not work!
});
```

So the first part works perfectly, when i hover throw the an area with `class="anyClass"`, this area gets a new `class="anyClass hovered"`.

When i leave this area with the mouse both classes stay, why?

Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're attaching the event listener once - when the code is run (assuming this is in `$(document).ready(` or the like).  There aren't any elements that match the selector `area.hovered`, so no event listener.  Instead, use event delegation:

```
$("area").on('mouseleave', '.hovered', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

Setting the second parameter to a selector means that it'll add the listener to all elements matching `area` and then on the `mouseleave` event, check that they also match `.hovered`, calling the function if they do.

[jQuery docs on `.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: @user3297073 Does my answer not explain itself?